# Turning off Default database monitor switches

Tags: db2

IF i turn off this parameter at instance level((DFT_MON_TABLE)) . will it remove monitoring on all the tables under that particular instance ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting `DFT_MON_TABLE` to `OFF` means that DB2 will not populate the monitoring elements controlled by this switch starting when the database(s) in the instance are activated.  This does not mean that DB2 isn't monitoring, though:  you (or another user) can still enable this switch for their particular session using the `UPDATE MONITOR SWITCHES USING TABLE ON`.